# Query is working well in mysql but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

The query is working well in mysql but not in php. 
I am getting only tuesday's value after implementing inner join in php. There are two tables monday and tuesday. On selecting lab1 from monday and lab1 from tuesday, just tuesday's lab1 is showing.

P.S. the query is working in mysql.

```
<form action="lab.php" method="POST">
    Check routine for : <select name="new">
        <option name="lab1">LAB1</option>
        <option name="lab2">LAB2</option>
        <option name="lab3">LAB3</option>
        <option name="lab4">LAB4</option>
    </select>&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php
require 'conn.php';
if(isset($_POST['new'])&& !empty($_POST['new']))
{
        $lab=$_POST['new'];
        $lab=strtolower($lab);
        $result = mysql_query("select  monday.time,
        monday.$lab,tuesday.$lab from monday inner join 
        tuesday where monday.time=tuesday.time");

        echo "<table BORDER='1' width='50%' cellpadding='3'>
        <tr> 
            <th colspan='7'><h2>$lab</h2></th> 
        </tr>

        <tr> 
            <th>TIME</th>
            <th>MONDAY</th>
            <th>TUESDAY</th>

        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {   echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td>" .$row['time']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row[$lab]. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row[$lab]. "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";


}

?>
```

Comment: You have an sql injection problem, using un-filtered / un-whitelisted user input for your column names is very dangerous.

Comment: I can deal with sql injection later, but can you tell me why the query is not working in php?

Comment: Putting aside the SQL injection vulnerability in your code, what is the output of  `echo "select  monday.time, monday.$lab,tuesday.$lab from monday inner join tuesday where monday.time=tuesday.time` " ?

Comment: The output is only coming from tuesday able and the tuesday column is repeating monday's column. you can see the output table here.

http://postimg.org/image/jp9t85roz/

Comment: The repetition is due to the fact that you have $row[$lab] in your iteration instead of $row['columnname']

Comment: Even if I am using the column-name, it is repeating @jacek_podwysocki

Comment: `<option>` does not hold name attributes, only `<select>` so change those `name=` for the options to `value=` most likely the reason. If that works, let me know and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Ok, so where are we at here? ^

Comment: It is still the same @Fred-ii-

Comment: Did you remove the extra `echo "<td>" .$row[$lab]. "</td>";`?

Comment: After removing that, this is coming. http://postimg.org/image/vjjrp6uld/

Comment: Well, remove `<th>TUESDAY</th>` - or did you want to also show Tuesday? Hard to say really what the ultimate goal is. Show only what from which table and for what day(s)?

Comment: I want to show tuesday also. that is why I am using inner join to take data from different table (i.e. monday and tuesday).

I want to show lab1(this is the actual column name of monday table in mysql) from monday table and lab1(this is the actual column name of tuesday table in mysql) from tuesday .

Comment: `monday.$lab,tuesday.$lab` that is another reason why. You're getting `$lab` from your POST select and it doubles from there. So, either you modify your query, or use another fetching method. Try changing `monday.$lab,tuesday.$lab` to `monday.$lab,tuesday.time`

Comment: can you share you table structure for better understanding.

Comment: How can I use another fetching method?

Comment: This is monday table: http://postimg.org/image/k9sb6mkih/
tuesday: http://postimg.org/image/zehgjjaw9/

@NavjotSingh

Comment: Many ways to do this. Checkboxes, radio buttons, another dropdown select. Make a new variable for it and pass it over for the 2nd day then use variable #2 in your query and echos.

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii- for helping out. Thanks Navjot Singh again.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to see you found your solution, *cheers!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it works.

```
 <?php
    require 'conn.php';
    if(isset($_POST['new'])&& !empty($_POST['new']))
    {
            $lab=$_POST['new']; 
            $lab=strtolower($lab);
            $result = mysql_query("select  monday.time,
            monday.$lab,tuesday.$lab as labval from monday inner join 
            tuesday where monday.time=tuesday.time") or die(mysql_error());

            echo "<table BORDER='1' width='50%' cellpadding='3'>
            <tr> 
                <th colspan='7'><h2>$lab</h2></th> 
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <th>TIME</th>
                <th>MONDAY</th>
                <th>TUESDAY</th>

            </tr>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {   echo "<tr>";

                        echo "<td>" .$row['time']. "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" .$row[$lab]. "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" .$row['labval']. "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";


    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you Navjot Singh. It is working. This is great! Thank you very much.

Comment: It should be noted and added in the answer, that the OP is using name attributes in the select's options. Only select has the name attribute, not option. It needs to be `value=` and not `name=` for all `<option>` tags.